# Running a server on a separate thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, activex

I have a program that retrieves data from a serial device, and then puts it in a server that is accessible by certain programs that can handle this protocol. This server is a third party program that is in the form of an active x control.

The hardware devices require a Thread.Sleep, which is unfortunate. The programs that monitor the server sometimes query the server during the time when a thread is sleeping. This causes it to think the server has failed.

My next idea was to put the server on a separate thread, one solely dedicated for the server tasks. In the UI thread, I run the following code:

```
        Thread workerThread = new Thread(DoServerWork);
        workerThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        workerThread.Start();
```

In the delegate, I have

```
    public void DoServerWork()
    {
        rtu = new AxASMBSLVLib.AxASMBSLV();
        rtu.CreateControl();
        rtu.BeginInit();
        rtu.OpenPort();

        while (true)
        {

        }
    }
```

The problem is that the server starts to work, and then becomes unresponsive in about 5 seconds. My initial thought is that the thread is exiting, but the while(true) should prevent that from happening. Any thoughts?

Comment: The `while(true)` will eat up a lot of CPU time. Didn't  you hear the fans gearing up?

Comment: Yeah, I know. I initially had a Thread.Sleep(1) in there, but the same problem was happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is a modbus TCP/IP slave from a third party company. The first option is to "drag and drop" it from the toolbox to the GUI, causing it to be on the UI thread.

Since ActiveX requires STA : exactly the right thing.

> I must call Thread.Sleep on the UI thread,

that should never be necessary, here lies your real problem. Never block/sleep he main thread.

Your question should be about how to avoid the Sleep().

Comment: Yeah, I guess you are right. Looks like I am going to have to be more creative on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are running this in a Single Threaded Apartment (STA), once that thread hits the empty endless loop, nothing more can happen. An endless loop is generally not a good idea. You should probably use a timer to periodically perform the server work in its OnElapsed event handler.

Comment: The only issue with this is that the server needs to be ready all the time to respond to requests from the external program. I just didn't know how to keep this thread running forever besides an endless loop.

Comment: You need to run the server with async (blocking) I/O. The only sensible option.

Comment: How would I go about implementing this in my case?

Comment: Well, I have no clue what an AxASMBSLV is. But are you sure you even need a thread?

Comment: It is a modbus TCP/IP slave from a third party company. The first option is to "drag and drop" it from the toolbox to the GUI, causing it to be on the UI thread. Due to hardware limitations, I must call Thread.Sleep on the UI thread, which would cause a program reading values from the modbus server to think that the modbus server has failed because it did not respond. The idea I had was to have this server running on a totally separate and dedicated thread as to never have this problem. Does this make more sense?

Comment: _"Due to hardware limitations, I must call Thread.Sleep on the UI thread"_ makes no sense at all. Go back to that point.

Comment: By hardware limitations, I mean the remote devices that my program is interacting with. I am not referring to the computer hardware. The issue is that the Active X control was originally running on the UI thread, where the Thread.Sleep was being called. This was causing the modbus server to appear unresponsive by the program reading values from the modbus server.